# Cannot get groupby records based on their minimum value using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following csv

```
id;price;editor
k1;10,00;ed1
k1;8,00;ed2
k3;10,00;ed1
k3;11,00;ed2
k2;10,50;ed1
k1;9,50;ed3
```

If I do the following

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('Testing.csv', delimiter =';')
df_reduced= df.groupby(['id', 'editor'])['price'].min()
```

Instead of getting

```
k1;8,00;ed2
k2;10,50;ed1
k3;10,00;ed1
```

I get

```
k1;10,00;ed1
    8,00;ed2
    9,50;ed3
k2;10,50;ed1
k3;10,00;ed1
   11,00;ed2
```

So can I get three id's with their minimum values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group the data by only id and find min price for each group. Index the original dataframe based on the minimum values to include the editor column.

Note: I am assuming that the comma in price column is a typo

```
df.loc[df['price'] == df.groupby('id')['price'].transform('min')]


    id  price   editor
1   k1  8.0     ed2 
2   k3  10.0    ed1 
4   k2  10.5    ed1
```

Comment: how to print and check?

Comment: How to print what?

Comment: the results on screen :)

Comment: Do you mean print the dataframe? Use print(df)?

Comment: print(df) would print them all can I print(df.loc[df['price']) ?

Comment: if you want to print only price, you can print(df['price'])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190794/discussion-between-evridiki-and-vaishali).

Answer (score 5):

`drop_duplicate` + `sort_values`

```
#df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'].str.replace(",", "."))

df.sort_values('price').drop_duplicates(['id'])
Out[423]: 
   id  price editor
1  k1    8.0    ed2
2  k3   10.0    ed1
4  k2   10.5    ed1
```

Comment: I know it really doesn't matter but, which should be the correct order, k1, k2 k3 or k1, k3, k2?

Comment: If I had another column of availability , and I would like the minimum but of only the availables I should do df.sort_values('price').sort_values('availability').drop_duplicates(['id]) ?

Comment: @Evridiki `df.sort_values(['price','availability']).drop_duplicates(['id'])`

Comment: sort_values(['price','availability'==1])  for available?

Answer (score 4):

Much like @Wen-Ben I choose to use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`, however, I converted the values using `pd.read_csv` with the `decimal` parameter.

```
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""id;price;editor
k1;10,00;ed1
k1;8,00;ed2
k3;10,00;ed1
k3;11,00;ed2
k2;10,50;ed1
k1;9,50;ed3""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter =';', decimal=',')

df.sort_values(['id','price']).drop_duplicates(['id'])
```

Output:

```
   id  price editor
1  k1    8.0    ed2
4  k2   10.5    ed1
2  k3   10.0    ed1
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction

```
df_reduced= df.groupby(['id', 'editor'])['price'].min()
```

will give you the min price per each unique id-editor pair, you want the min per id. However, since your price field has a string format, you first need to cast it to numeric in order to run the groupby:

```
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['price'].str.replace(",", "."))
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['price'].idxmin()]
```

Output

```
   id  price editor
1  k1    8.0    ed2
4  k2   10.5    ed1
2  k3   10.0    ed1
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the editor part:

```
df_reduced= df.groupby(['id'])['price'].min()
```

no need to include 'transformed' as somebody else stated

Comment: haha, good thing is that others provided good answers, so we can all learn